# Jest open handle RANDOMBYTESREQUEST on NestJS GraphQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm having the following error when

```sh
jest --runInBand --detectOpenHandles
```

```sh
Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  RANDOMBYTESREQUEST

      3 | import { UserAuth } from 'src/auth/dto/user.jwt';
      4 | 
    > 5 | export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
        |                            ^
      6 |   (data: unknown, context: ExecutionContext): UserAuth => {
      7 |     const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
      8 |     return ctx.getContext().req.user;

      at rng (node_modules/uuid/dist/rng.js:18:21)
      at Object.v4 (node_modules/uuid/dist/v4.js:17:63)
      at Object.createParamDecorator (node_modules/@nestjs/common/decorators/http/create-route-param-metadata.decorator.js:14:30)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/common/guards/current-user.guard.ts:5:28)
```

Based on my investigation this error comes from package crypto on UUID module inside of
`import { createParamDecorator} from '@nestjs/common';`

all the tests are passing but jest is not exiting, my file is the following:

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { UserAuth } from 'src/auth/dto/user.jwt';

export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, context: ExecutionContext): UserAuth => {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    return ctx.getContext().req.user;
  }
);
```

and the test:

```
describe('AuthService', () => {
  let service: AuthService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        rootMongooseTestModule(),
        PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
        CacheModule.register(),
        TwilioModule.forRoot({
          accountSid: process.env.ACCOUNT_SID,
          authToken: process.env.AUTH_TOKEN,
        }),
        UserModule,
      ],
      providers: [AuthService, AuthResolver, AuthConfig, CookieService, JwtStrategy],
      exports: [AuthService],
      controllers: [AuthController],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<AuthService>(AuthService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  afterAll(async (done) => {
    await closeInMongoDConnection();
    done();
  });
});
```

I have tried to:

- mock the uuid.v4 but then other tests started to failed
- mock the decorator but then the guard decorator fails

Any idea how to fix this issues?

Answer (score -1):

The solution for me was to change AfterAll to afterEach